# MSVS reopen last solution on startup

Tags: visual-studio

does anybody know how can I configure MS Visual Studio to reopen last solution when it starts?

I traversed probably all menus, settings etc. and cannot find it. It does not seem possible to not support this feature, or am I wrong?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio supports this feature.

You have to open the Options Dialog via menu bar **Tools -> Options** and then select the **Environment** category and choose **StartUp**.

Here you will find a combobox for the action to perform **At Startup**.

*Screenshot Visual Studio 2017:*
[image: Load last loaded solution]